# Responsive HTML Elements with Specified Dimension Content

Tags: html, css

I try to create responsive HTML elements whenever the browser width is wide enough, it fills with 3 horizontal box elements whose content can be text or an image. When text content doesn't fill the whole box, it leaves some empty space so that it doesn't wrapped around the box.

However the text content can fill the box. Whether the box is filled or not, it should have same dimension unless the browser dimension changes.

When browser dimension is widening, the 3 elements should stay with the original dimension. But when it is narrowing, the 3 horizontal elements can reduce to 2 horizontal elements, leaving the other element to new space. And it can be 1 horizontal element if the browser space is narrow enough.

There can be many 3 horizontal elements, like this:

```
X X X
X X X
X X X
```

They're stacked like a table.
When the content is an image, its size must comply to the box dimension not the other way around, so it shrinks when the original image is bigger than the box or stretch when the image is smaller.

so far this is what I have
[my JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ethereal1m/Lj69qxhp/)

The code above have a responsive horizontal box. Also the picture doesn't comply to the box but vice versa.

Please advice.

Comment: Use one of the many css grid systems that does exactly what you need.

Comment: @morels please be specific, I'm still a beginner

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @ethereal1m do a couple of tutorials with Bootstrap, 960 grid system or Zurb Foundation. They all are good free css frameworks that offer you the features you need.

Comment: Sounds like flexbox is exactly what you need here. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes and http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: thanks you guys, im using flexbox and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design won't be obtained by using Width and height elements.

Try setting these to Min-height / Max-height etc..

Also if you really want to keep it responsive then you should just install the bootstrap framework and use

col-md-4 to achieve this much easier without having to worry about css styling etc..